# Angular 5 component-less route with guard fails to hit redirect

Tags: angular, angular5

I am attempting to setup a component-less route to apply a route guard in Angular 5 as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always', canActivateChild:[AppRouteGuard], children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'get-started', redirectTo: 'get-started', pathMatch: 'full'},

]}];
```

Unfortunately, it seems like the redirectTo 'main' is not being invoked. However, the following does work:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always', canActivateChild:[AppRouteGuard], children: [
    { path: '', component: MainComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'get-started', redirectTo: 'get-started', pathMatch: 'full'},

]}];
```

Is there a reason that only the later works? Is there a way to make the redirectTo: 'main' work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Component-less routes “consume” URL segments without instantiating components. This doesn't mean there is no component associated with the route.

In your case, when you try to redirect to 'main' . there is no routing Info available for this 'main' route so it fails. You should define main route after redirect config like shown below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always', canActivateChild:[AppRouteGuard], 
children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/main', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'main', component: MainComponent },

]}];
```

Simple example of component-less route:

```
 [
  {
    path: 'team/:id',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: TeamListComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: TeamDetailsComponent,
        outlet: 'aux'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Since there is no component associated with the `/team/:id` route, the router will merge its `params`, `data`, and resolve into the `children`. As a result, `TeamListComponent` and `TeamDetailsComponent` can access the `id` parameter directly, without going through the parent route.

Comment: Thank for for the clarification on this! This makes sense and resolved my issue.

Comment: glad to help! :)